# How to implement wordpress pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have looked for pagination scripts and put them in the code below but nothing works, how do I implement pagination below?

```
'<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

  <div id="pbox">

    <div id="pthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'mythumbnail')); ?></a></div>
        <div id="pcontent">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />

Post Category: <b><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></b>



        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

You need to pass `paged` parameter inside argument.and then pass `max_num_pages` in function `paginate_links`

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 ,'paged'=>$paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ($the_query ->have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
 ?>
<div id="pbox">

    <div id="pthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'mythumbnail')); ?></a></div>
        <div id="pcontent">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ptitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />

Post Category: <b><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></b>



        </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Ok it worked showing the pagination links however when I click on any number example 2 or 3 it shows just the main page list of posts why?

Comment: after click on page number , is it redirect you to same page or another page? @TimSharpe

Comment: another page just with same posts on it

Comment: Okay .please set default permalink from backend side (wp-admin) and then check again.! @TimSharpe

Comment: I have tried changing the permalink to all choices and it still does not correct it

Comment: change 'format' parameter to '/page/%#%'...'format' => '/page/%#%'....and  also echo $paged variable..@TimSharpe

Comment: This is what the code looks like now but still does not work... 
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
echo $paged;
wp_reset_query(); ?>'